# How to enable deliveryAttemptHeader to get DefaultErrorHandler retry count when using spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` and have implemented stateful retry using `DefaultErrorHandler`, I found that by enabling `deliveryAttemptHeader` of container properties I can access the retry count or `deliveryAttempt` count from message header but I am not able to enable it.

I tried to set the value to `true` as below

```java
@Bean
  public ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> containerCustomizer(
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory) {
    ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> custCustomizer = container -> {
      container.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
    };
    factory.setContainerCustomizer(custCustomizer);
    return custCustomizer;
  }
```

With this configuration when I start the application and debug [KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L1078](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/21e2cf7debd9fa5a9532e6343e2384c031ae766a/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L1078) I still see that `deliveryAttemptHeader` is disabled, and also the `ContainerCustomizer` instance that I have created is also not getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring-cloud-stream` does not use Boot's container factory; use its `ListenerContainerCustomizer` instead.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_advanced_consumer_configuration